# How to get frames from video using python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, video

I am try to get frames with OpenCV but its not working with python 3.5.

I used the following code,this is working fine with python 2.7 but not with 3.5 :

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('myvideo.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()
success = True
while success:
  success,image = vidcap.read()
  # print 'Read a new frame: ', success
  cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image)   # save frame as JPEG
```

is there changes in syntax.??
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `ffmpeg` using:

`sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`

and then install `ffmpy`:

`pip3 install ffmpy`

```
import ffmpy

ff = ffmpy.FFmpeg(inputs={'path_of_video.mp4':None },outputs={'frame.jpg': '-ss 00:00:02 -t 00:00:2 -s 400x400 -r 1 -f mjpeg'})

ff.run()
```